# does my certificate have OCSP No Check Extension?

Tags: digital-signature, bouncycastle, x509, digital-certificate, x509certificate2

Some certificates have OCSP some certificates Only CRL some certificates neither of all.

how can I see,  if certificate have or does not have   "OCSP No Check Extension " using bouncicastle ro javas classes?

thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCSP No Check is an unusual extension. It's typically only present in OCSP delegate certificates. That said, look for an extension with OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1.5. That's noCheck.